# Window.Print() throws permission denied JavaScript run-time exception in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, modernizr

I am facing a strange issue, While printing a page using window.print(), I am getting the print preview for the first time.But when I click for the second time, I am getting permission denied JavaScript run-time exception(it is triggering from modernizr.js file)

Does anybody knows why this issue occurs. I am facing this issue only in ie(7 and 8).
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Sooraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by replacing the modernizr with the latest version. They have fixed the issue associated with internet explorer. Hope this might help someone facing this issue.